# ASP.NET C# stop showing today date in hijri

Tags: c#

I have an issue regarding showing today date using C#, when I use this code to get today date and show it in label I get the date in hijri I don't know why even that my settings in control panel and in my Windows 10 is displayed in georgian.

Here is the code I am using:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;

Label1.Text = dt.ToString();
```

Here is the result:

```
21/10/43 06:50:19 ص
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: When does the us issue occur? On your computer when debugging or when deployed to a server (that might be set to Hiring) and accessing from your computer?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by using the code below:

```
using System.Globalization;

CultureInfo french = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR");

String dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", french);
```